# How to move progress bar slider/pointer between two dates?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pointers, progress-bar

I have developed progress bar with html, css and javascript/jQuery.
Now am trying to move vertical line slider / pointer image as the days progress towards end date. Slider / Pointer should move only between start date and end date.

Here's the fiddle link I tried so far:
[Updated JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/RichaFerna/n3f16gzu/62/)

Am having issues with javascript. Below is the code:

```
var start = new Date(2021, 3, 20), 
  end = new Date(2021, 4, 20), 
  today = new Date(), 
  p = Math.round(((today - start) / (end - start)) * 100) + '%';
// Update the progress bar
$('img').css("margin-left", p).after().append(p);
```

Also the slider / pointer is moving outside the container. Hope I get help from you all experts :)

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: First of all, what issue are you having? Second, your jsfiddle doesn't have any javascript

Comment: @vanowm, I have updated the jsfiddle link. Issue am facing is with the vertical blue line image which is moving away from the progress bar when today date is closer to end date. I think the issue is in last line of javascript but don't know the fix.

Comment: Replaces last line of jQuery with element.style.marginleft =p. I got closer to solution but still image is moving after right side div when its 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `today` can be outside of the two dates, you'll need restrict `p` to 0-100.
Also, your image has very wide border on each side, which showed outside of the area.

```js
var start = new Date(2021, 3, 20), 
    end = new Date(2021, 4, 20), 
    today = new Date(),
    p =  Math.max(0, Math.min(100, Math.round(((today - start) / (end - start)) * 100))) + "%";

// Update the progress bar
$('.indicator').css("width", p).find("span").text(p);

// update start/end dates
$('.ldate').text(start.getDate() + "/" + (start.getMonth()+1) + "/" + start.getFullYear());
$('.rdate').text(end.getDate() + "/" + (end.getMonth()+1) + "/" + end.getFullYear());

//demo
p = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, Math.round(((today - start) / (end - start)) * 100)));
!function slider()
{
  $('.indicator').css("width", p + "%").find("span").text(p + "%");
  if (++p > 100)
    p = 0;
  
  setTimeout(slider, 200);
}()
```

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.container .pbcolor {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
/*  padding: 23px 10px; */
  background: #ffedc4;
}
.container .mdate {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fcfcfc;
}
.container .mdate .ldate {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.container .mdate .rdate {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

/* added */
.container .indicator {
  min-width: 2px;
  top: 0px;
/*  border: 1px solid black; */
  overflow: hidden;

  background-image: url('https://www.linkpicture.com/q/vlt_1_1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right;

  text-align: center;
}
.pbcolor
{
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}
.indicator > img
{
  height: 65px;
  float: right;
}

.ltext
{
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
.rtext
{
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px; /* same as padding in .container */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="pbcolor">
      <div class="ltext">Text on left</div>
      <div class="indicator">
<!--        <img src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/vlt_1_1.png"> -->
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="rtext">Text on right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdate">
       <span class="ldate">20/4/2021</span><span class="rdate">20/5/2021</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the image was 2px wide, it would be shown correctly, because of the "incorrect" dimensions it shows away from the right edge and before 25% it shows at wrong dimensions.

Comment: Thank you @vanowm for your time and help. Appreciate it. For demonstration purpose I downloaded free public domain image and did not checked its border. Is there a way for me to get image without border, also 2px line so that I can test it in jsfiddle? Also I see you have changed structure of html a bit. Will try doing that in my source code too. Thank you

Comment: @vanown this is perfect. You are genius. Marking answer as correct. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: Hi @vanown, if I want to add two fixed texts inside progress bar region, one at left side and the other at right side. How to do it? If I add another div or span, I get two percentage texts

Comment: @Richa I've updated the code with text on each side.

Comment: Thank you again @vanowm for your kind help

Comment: if I have to shrink the container and fit all the content inside the container what I should do? I was trying to make width as 200px and height as 70px. If I try css .container{width:200px;height:70px;}, the layout is getting all messed up. Hope I get some help with this. Thanks